# Almacenar variable de sesión en CONTROLADOR, recuperarlas en la VISTA - LARAVEL 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Amigos que tal, estoy usando las sessiones en `LARAVEL`, hasta ahora solo he declarado la `session` en el controlador pero no lo puedo mostrar en la vista.

Estoy sessionando el `nombre` de la habitación para usarlo en la `vista` pero no se la sintaxis correcta.

Mi Código del controlador:

```
public function index($id){
    $habitacion = Habitaciones::where('id',$id)->first();

    session(['nombre_habitacion' => $habitacion->nombre]);

    //sigue el codigo
}
```

Quizás estoy mal en el controlador, la idea es mostrar el valor en la `view` mediante una `session`.

Answer (score 2):

Para mostrarlo en la vista solo basta con que lo escribas con la sintaxis del doble corchete:

```
{{ session('nombre_habitacion') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#storing-data), la asignacion de la session, estaría correcta.

Ahora bien, para mostrar el valor en la vista, tendrias que hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

`{{ session('nombre_habitacion') }}`

o

`{{ request()->session()->get('nombre_habitacion') }}`

Tambien antes de mostrar podrías consultar si existe valor en esa variable

```
@if(Session::has('nombre_habitacion'))
  {{ Session::get('nombre_habitacion')}}
@endif
```

Hay varias opciones.